# That async-ing feeling - httpclient and mvc thread blocking

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, caching, async-await

Dilemma, dilemma...

I've been working up a solution to a problem that uses async calls to the `HttpClient` library (`GetAsync=>ConfigureAwait(false)` etc). IIn a console app, my dll is very responsive and the mixture of using the async await calls and the `Parallel.ForEach(=>)` really makes me glow.

Now for the issue. After moving from this test harness to the target app, things have become problematic. I'm using asp.net mvc 4 and have hit a few issues. The main issue really is that calling my process on a controller action actually blocks the main thread until the async actions are complete. I've tried using an `async` controller pattern, I've tried using `Task.Factory`, I've tried using `new Threads`. You name it, I've tried all the flavours - and then some!.

Now, I appreciate that the nature of http is not designed to facilitate long processes like this and there are a number of articles here on SO that say don't do it. However, there are mitigating reasons why i NEED to use this approach. The main reason that I need to run this in mvc is due to the fact that I actually update the live data cache (on the mvc app) in realtime via raising an event in my  dll's code. This means that fragments of the 50-60 data feeds can be pushed out live before the entire async action is complete. Therefore, client apps can receive partial updates within seconds of the async action being instigated. If I were to delegate the process out to a console app that ran the entire process in the background, I'd no longer be able to harness those fragment partial updates and this is the raison d'etre behind the entire choice of this architecture.

Can anyone shed light on a solution that would allow me to mitigate the blocking of the thread, whilst at the same time, allow each async fragment to be consumed by my object model and fed out to the client apps (I'm using `signalr` to make these client updates). A kind of *nirvanna* would be a scenario where an out-of-process cache object could be shared between numerous processes - the cache update could then be triggered and consumed by my mvc process (aka - http://devproconnections.com/aspnet-mvc/out-process-caching-aspnet). And so back to reality...

I have also considered using a secondary webservice to achieve this, but would welcome other options before once again `over engineering` my solution (there are already many moving parts and a multitude of async `Actions` going on).

Sorry not to have added any code, I'm hoping for practical philosophy/insights, rather than code help on this, tho would of course welcome coded examples that illustrate a solution to my problem.

I'll update the question as we move in time, as my thinking process is still maturing on this.

**[edit]** - for the sake of clarity, the snippet below is my brothers grimm code collision (extracted from a larger body of work):

```
Parallel.ForEach(scrapeDataBases, new ParallelOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 15
}, 
async dataBase =>
{
    await dataBase.ScrapeUrlAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    await UpdateData(dataType, (DataCheckerScrape)dataBase);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

`async` and `Parallel.ForEach` do not mix naturally, so I'm not sure what your console solution looks like. Furthermore, `Parallel` should almost never be used on ASP.NET at all.

It sounds like what you would want is to just use `Task.WhenAll`.

On a side note, I think your reasoning around background processing on ASP.NET is incorrect. It is perfectly possible to have a separate process that updates the clients via SignalR.

Comment: hi stephen, nice to make contact, i've read a few of your articles. especially recently on this voayage of discovery. the mix of those two approaches may well prduce an ugly offspring, but they do actually *appear* to work in the context of my console app. i get what your saying about background processing being legit in aps.net. however, thus far, none of my strategies have harnessed the approach without blocking the main thread. this of course is definitely down to my inexperience in this department.

Comment: ... ran out odf space... to continue! however, i definitely also feel that my battle here could be won by using components like redis or appfabric and simply spawning out to a process and allowing the process to make changes to the cache and my mvc subscription to that cache item would be picked up. again, just to point out, you are instrumental in me being in this position today, thanks to your wonderful articles on *t'internet* ;)

Comment: @StephenCleary hi mate, where can I read about using `Parallel` in `ASP.NET`??? Can you explain why?

Comment: stephen, i've added my mixed ugly drunk child process invocation into my question to let you see what the h3ll i'm attempting. hope it helps.

Comment: btw - i'm *half thinking* that using azure (appfabric) as a totally seperate entity purely for a shared common cache for a windows service and the mvc client *may* be a pragmatic solution that has hidden benefits moving fwd (i.e using the notifications for a bunch of diffewrent apps to allow them to perform different functions based on the partial updates (sms services being an old skool example of using the subscription model against the cache updates in an app that listens for cache updates ...etc, etc). just my miserly scots thinking!

Comment: ok, i've made some headway using a little lib that you mentioned on one of your posts: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/quickstart.html. this seems quite promising and doesn't appear to block the main thread in any way... will keep you posted (oh and I changed the Parallel.ForEach to a normal foreach block for good measure and all works the same as before  - so hopefully less moving parts now.

Comment: The code you posted for `ForEach` is not something I'd recommend; the `async` delegate in that code is returning `void` (not `Task`), which should certainly be avoided. In fact, it's troubling that MVC let you get away with it at all (it should have raised an exception) - so ensure you are targeting 4.5 and [have `targetFramework` set to 4.5 in your `web.config`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx)...

Comment: Instead of `foreach`/`ForEach`, try doing a LINQ `Select`, as such: `scrapeOddsBases.Select(async oddsBase => ...).ToArray()`. This will result in an array of tasks, which you can await using `await Task.WhenAll(...)`. This is the asynchronous way to do concurrency. I have not used Hangfire myself but it's certainly better than keeping the work in-memory in the ASP.NET app. :)

Comment: @IamStalker: [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/02/08/9960003.aspx) is a good overview of parallelism on ASP.NET. Using `Parallel` is usually not necessary since ASP.NET already has its built-in parallelism (and in the majority of cases, `Parallel` will actually actively interfere with the ASP.NET parallelism). There are rare exceptions, but in general `Parallel` on ASP.NET should be avoided.

Comment: stephen -thanks for the wise pointers, i'll try the approach suggested and see wher eit takes us.

Answer (score 1):

Being that your question is pretty high level without a lot of code.  You could try Reactive Extensions.

Something like

```
private IEnumerable<Task<Scraper>> ScrappedUrls()
{
    // Return the 50 to 60 task for each website here. 
    // I assume they all return the same type.
    // return .ScrapeUrlAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public  async Task<IEnumerable<ScrapeOdds>> GetOdds()
{
    var results = new Collection<ScrapeOdds>();
    var urlRequest = ScrappedUrls();
    var observerableUrls = urlRequest.Select(u => u.ToObservable()).Merge();
    var publisher = observerableUrls.Publish();
    var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<OddsHub>();
    publisher.Subscribe(scraper =>
        {
            // Whatever you do do convert to the result set
            var scrapedOdds = scraper.GetOdds();
            results.Add(scrapedOdds);

            // update anything else you want when it arrives.

            // Update SingalR here 
            hubContext.Clients.All.UpdatedOdds(scrapedOdds);
        });
    // Will fire off subscriptions and not continue until they are done.
    await publisher;
    return results;
}
```

The merge option will process the results as they come in.  You can then update the signalR hubs plus whatever else you need to update as they come in.  The controller action will have to wait for them all to come in.  That's why there is an await on the publisher.

I don't really know if httpClient is going to like to have 50 - 60 web calls all at once or not.  If it doesn't you can just take the IEnumerable to an array and break it down into a smaller chunks.  And also there should be some error checking in there.  With Rx you can also tell it to SubscribeOn and ObserverOn different threads but I think with everything being pretty much async that wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: charles, thanks for the answer. it looks like it's an interesting take, tho i would of course in the *real* code raise an event to the client and let it handle the hubContext events. therefore, your code would have no knowledge of the hubs context, but the principle seems feasible. i'll explore. thanks - oh and +1

Comment: You can check out this http://www.nhail.com/rx/processing-tasks-as-they-complete-with-rx/ for an example of how RX can process a Task[] when they complete instead of Task.WhenAll